# Criteria builder IN clause with nested query for embedded @ElementCollection

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I have the `User` and `Address` entities (actually others but for simplify).

```
@Entity
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    protected long id;
    ...

    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name = "address",
        joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")})
    @Column(name = "street")
    private List<Address> addresses;

    ...
}

@Embeddable
public class Address {
    private String street;
    ...
}
```

How to make nested query for `Address` and use it in `IN` clause? Result query that I expect `select * from user u where u.id in (select user_id from address where street like '%Green%');

```
Root<User> root = ...; // Root query already exists

CriteriaQuery<Address> cq = builder.createQuery(Address.class);
Root<Address> addressRoot = cq.from(Address.class);

cq.select(addressRoot.get("user_id"))
    .where(
        builder.like(
            addressRoot.get("street"),
            "%Green%"
        )
    );

Predicate .... = criteriaQuery.where(root.get("id").in(cq))
```

I tried something like this, but it does not work - `Address` it is not entity and I can't create `CriteriaQuery` with it.
Important note: I can't use `root.join("addresses").get("street").like(...)` for several reasons

Answer (score 1):

You need to use an exists subquery, something like the following:

```
Root<User> root = ...; // Root query already exists

CriteriaQuery<Address> cq = builder.createQuery(Address.class);
Subquery<Integer> subquery = cq.subquery(Integer.class);
Root<User> correlatedRoot = subquery.correlate(root);
Join<User, Address> addressRoot = correlatedRoot.join("addresses");

cq.select(addressRoot.get("user_id"));
subquery.where(
        builder.like(
            addressRoot.get("street"),
            "%Green%"
        )
    );

Predicate .... = criteriaQuery.where(builder.exists(subquery));
```

Comment: I spent a few hours tweaking a subquery to get the desired results and none seem to work. Thankfully I found your answer which uses `Subquery#correlate()`.